# Why don't people Accept Answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, accepted-answer

I'll start off on a good note and congratulate everyone in the community for continually supporting each other. We have maintained a great answer rate here on 3D Printing SE with a answer rate of 96%. I believe this rate has been maintained since day one and it's hard to keep up, especially with fluctuations in user activity.

However, I would like to at least address an issue I've seen trending. Most of the issue comes from old posts and new, unfamiliar users to the SE network. Anyways, there is an abnormally high number of unaccepted answers.

Specifically, on 01/28/2017 9am Pacific US, there are **658 questions** ***with answers***, ***258*** of which have **no answer accepted**. This is an ***answer acceptance rate of about 40%***.

Updated to 11/16/2018 10am CET, there are **1682 questions** ***with answers*** (of a total of 1788 questions), ***706*** of which have **no answer accepted**. This is an ***answer acceptance rate of about 42%***, although improved, it is still very low!

---

Now, I've done this in the past with little payout, but perhaps if we have more eyes on it moving forward. I have gone through the list of questions [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1) and commented on the question to ask the OP if any of the answers helped solve their situation. Something like this (see also meta posting [Do we have Standardised Comments?](/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments)):

> Hello @[UserName], I noticed your question has been up for a while now. Have any of the answers below been able to solve your question? If so, would you mind accepting the appropriate answer. If not, what is missing so that we may help you further? Also, if you have figured it out on your own, you can always answer and accept your own solution. Thank you.

This should hopefully ping the user. Also, going through these questions may bring up questions that may need moderator attention/intervention.

Hopefully we can tackle this issue and get some other users more reputation in the process.

Comment: I have seen your template a few times, and have started using a similar one myself, so good idea! :-) However, if they don't respond, should we somehow handle it further? Is it perhaps common to close answered questions where no answer has been accepted?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to close a valid question, especially one with answers. I'll check around SE meta and let you know.

Comment: I have noticed that myself. There's not much we can do other than ping them. I'm guessing most people are not normal SO users and found us via our increasingly large google footprint. Then flag it as a duplicate as better questions are asked and accepted. Does the low acceptance effect our beta status? If not then we need not worry. But pinging is good.

Comment: @StarWind It doesn't directly affect our beta status, but the dormant reputation does. Of the 258 un-accepted questions, that ends up being 4386 reputation that just sitting there (3870 in answer reputation, 516 in accepting an answer). That could easily close a huge gap we have in "experienced" new users (200+ Rep). Plus, the more users feel like their work is being noticed with Rep, the more likely they are to continue to come back.

Comment: I tried it on http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/can-toothbrush-bristles-be-printed/1369#1369 I wanted to see if it would float to the top of the active list ( it did not) and I am happy to say that this did in fact work.

Comment: I went down the list of questions and tried it on the questions with top upvotes. We will see what happens. Didn't go to crazy, didn't want to hit a spam filter.

Comment: I'd just mention that 95 % answered is not such a big deal if you have 2.5 questions per day.

Comment: Is there a way for someone else to accept a well received answer if the OP never returns?  If so, I will formulate that into an answer.

Comment: Looks like there is not a way to "accept" and answer if the OP doesn't; but, there is a [lively discussion about this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature).

Comment: Accepting answers is a great thing. We, unfortunately, cannot force people to do it. The Stack Exchange network has a built in fall back on this, though, if you are wondering about the statistic. If an answer has an uptick on it, as far as the system is considered, the question is answered. An answer on a question just needs to be "well received", which to my understanding means it needs to be upvoted.

Comment: I always think that these controls look too disabled and they are placed at the wrong position. After reading the answer, why should someone scroll back to the top and then check something that looks disabled? Make it a button that says "This answer solved my problem". The controls on Aviation.SE don't look disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that a lot of the questions with non-accepted answers are users that came in for one or two questions and then left for good without ever accepting an answer. They might even have forgotten about this place.

For the note: we have (according to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/3dprinting.stackexchange.com)) 11,291 users that have joined (probably including spammers). Of these only 168 have gained 200 or more Rep, which is a quota of 1.488%. So only about 1.5% of the userbase has shown more than a glancing activity. 200 points equivalent to 40 votes on questions or 20 on answers, so it is a point showing at least some dedication to the stack.

Comment: Unless the users come from another stack, they could start with 101, then all your math halves. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hands up, guilty as charged. In my defence sometimes using the answer as given raises even more questions. In mitigation, from the knowledge gained (from helpful folk or simply own stupidity), I now contribute to others starting out. Will try harder.

P.S. Is there anywhere in the forum with a cure for life interrupting printing? Wife, dog, children, grandchildren all eat into my learning time....sigh.

Comment: well... we are not a forum... but the best cure for RL bugging into printing is dedicating time to it... and locking yourself with your printer for that time.

Comment: I added more screens in my life. Kitchen, bathroom, and car now have a screen on which I can watch educational content while I'm cooking, sitting on toilet, or stuck in traffic. Podcasts while exercising, etc... I try to maximize the value of what I watch and remove the mindless entertainment that teaches me nothing and/or gives no inspiration, such as- sports on which I have no money vested, any show involving "judges" or "reality", and anything on the "History" channel.

Comment: A fellow amateur radio operator of mine mentioned that he works out while he makes contacts (his radio shack is in the garage with his work out equipment) and he'll make a couple of contacts in between reps and ultimately "work out" for 3-4 hours.