# Featuring select Meta Posts so general users see them

Tags: discussion

A user from SE Meta recommended that we "feature" posts from our Meta that need more general user visibility and possibly draw more users into Meta.

Some recent examples might be:

- [Why are there so few votes](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/why-are-there-so-few-votes)
- [Accepting Answers](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/accepting-answers)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! I'm still pretty new to some of the moderator tools, and this the first time I have noticed the featured tag. I have added the featured tag to the questions you mention, so that they hopefully will show up sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

As a BTW, looking at the [edit history](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/241/revisions) of [Why don't members like our questions and answers?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/why-dont-members-like-our-questions-and-answers), it seems like the [featured](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag expires automatically.

> [image: Featured tag removal]

For the post in question the [featured](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added Aug 3 and by Sept 9 it was deleted, by Community. This post, [When and why is the [featured] tag removed by the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281797/when-and-why-is-the-featured-tag-removed-by-the-community-user), states that they are removed after 30 (or so) days:

> if we did not, every meta would be littered with dozens of forgotten "featured" questions over time.

---

Also, I can't seem to get it to work, I've just featured the [On-topic meta question](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276), but it doesn't seem to show up anywhere in a "Featured" box. Neither on 3D printing meta nor the main 3D printing site.

#### Update

It seems as if there is a little delay, at most 5-6 hours (I've tested it), between adding the featured flag and it appearing in a box:

> [image: Featured on meta]

It also appears to hang around in the box for another 12- 14 hours *after* the tag has been removed.